# how to place image at eight coordinates in canvas

Tags: android

![how place image with in 8 coordinates in canvas in android please help me to solve this 
problem, i need to move this image by next new 8 coordinates, these values are from text file help me to find a good solution  this problem [image: ][1]]

how place image with in 8 coordinates in canvas in android please help me to solve this 
problem, i need to move this image by next new 8 coordinates, these values are from text file help me on this problem

cordi.txt (it having like this)

200 110 600 110 200 740 600 740

200 111 600 111 200 741 600 741

200 112 600 112 200 742 600 742

200 113 600 113 200 743 600 743

200 114 600 114 200 744 600 744

// at here getting coordinates from text file

// at here i am drawing joing lines of coordinates but i need to place image with in the coordinates

but i find to place bitmap image at particular position of X,Y by this method 
 it working in linear motion moving up and down  ok perfect working but when there is not in linear coordinates that means (image rotation happed) at this time i am unable to find the angle of rotation of bitmap with axis can u give guide lines

```
    class image_placer extend view { 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(context1.getAssets().open("cordi.txt")));
                      String line;
                      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                       String[]  saLineElements = line.split("  ");
                      X1.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[0].toString().trim()));
                      Y1.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[1].toString().trim()));

                      X2.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[2].toString().trim()));
                      Y2.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[3].toString().trim()));

                      X3.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[4].toString().trim()));
                      Y3.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[5].toString().trim()));

                      X4.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[6].toString().trim()));
                      Y4.add(Integer.parseInt(saLineElements[7].toString().trim()));  
                  }
                  reader.close();
               } 
              catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                  System.err.println(
                     "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());
            }
// now in on draw method i need to place the image in that coordinates  i=0 (Globally declared )
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
                  if(i>=X1.size())
            {
                i=0;
                X=X1.get(i);
                Y=Y1.get(i);
                 dx=X2.get(i)-X1.get(i);
                dy=Y3.get(i)-Y1.get(i);
                Path drawPath=new Path();
                drawPath.moveTo(X1.get(i), Y1.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X2.get(i), Y2.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X4.get(i), Y4.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X3.get(i), Y3.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X1.get(i), Y1.get(i));    
               canvas.drawPath(drawPath, mPaint);

          }

            else
            {
                X=X1.get(i);
                Y=Y1.get(i);
                dx=X2.get(i)-X1.get(i);
                dy=Y3.get(i)-Y1.get(i);
                Path drawPath=new Path();
                drawPath.moveTo(X1.get(i), Y1.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X2.get(i), Y2.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X4.get(i), Y4.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X3.get(i), Y3.get(i));
                drawPath.lineTo(X1.get(i), Y1.get(i));    
               canvas.drawPath(drawPath, mPaint);
                i++;
            }
     float scaleWidth = (dx) / ballW;
        float scaleHeight = (dy) / ballH;
        if(i<=X1.size())
        {
        Matrix matrix_rev = new Matrix();
        matrix_rev.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(reverse, 0, 0,
                ballW, ballH, matrix_rev, true);
        }else{
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            if(i<=X1.size()-1)
           resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ball, 0, 0,
                    ballW, ballH, matrix, true);
        }

         canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap_img, X,Y, null);
             invalidate();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RectF dstRect=new RectF(x1,y1,width,height);
Canvas can=new Canvas();
can.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, paint);
```

Comment: this solution ok for the image's sides  parallel to the y axis or X axis but at here its make angle to the axis any solution